# Can't make bottom textfield stick on top of keyboard when it show up in chat app, Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I m developing a chat app which read and write data from firebase.
I have a streambuilder(that shows the messages)which is above a Container widget(which hold the input text field)

My problem is when I tap the input field and the keyboard pop ups, it cover the message textfield.

I have done many solutions from Stackoverflow and none of them seems to work in my case. The technique i have tried are 
      -resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true
      -Expanded(when I try this the messages no longer show up)
      -Flexible

I test the same code in my other project and it works. The text field stick on top of the keyboard. It just doesn't work in a particular project which use Bloc Pattern. There might have been some scaffold error or I don't know. Please help

```
import 'chat_design.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'chat_screen';

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String messageText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);

              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            MessagesStream(),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        //Do something with the user input.
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      //Implement send functionality.
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').limit(100).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        //wait before data is loaded
        if(snapshot.data == null) return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 7,),
            ),
          ],
        );


        final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.data['text'];
          final messageSender = message.data['sender'];

          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;



          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            isMe :currentUser == messageSender,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }

        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageBubble({this.sender, this.text,this.isMe});
  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final bool isMe;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            sender,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12.0,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            borderRadius: isMe ? BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(15.0))
                :BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
            color: isMe ? Colors.lightBlueAccent: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                '$text',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In SafeArea try to add your MessagesStream() in Expanded widget

Answer (score 3):

Take ListView or SingleChildScrollView under Body. And then use bottomNavigationBar in Scaffold.

```
Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
          color: Colors.grey[300],
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Type a message',
                ),
              ))
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is use a SingleChildScrollView, the content will scroll when the keyboard show up, will let you two examples:

```
// Flutter code sample for

// In this example, the children are spaced out equally, unless there's no more
// room, in which case they stack vertically and scroll.
//
// When using this technique, [Expanded] and [Flexible] are not useful, because
// in both cases the "available space" is infinite (since this is in a viewport).
// The next section describes a technique for providing a maximum height constraint.

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WidgetsApp(
      title: 'Flutter Code Sample',
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget navigator) {
        return MyStatelessWidget();
      },
      color: const Color(0xffffffff),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
        return Scrollbar( 
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  // A fixed-height child.
                  color: const Color(0xff808000), // Yellow
                  height: 120.0,
                ),
                Container(
                  // Another fixed-height child.
                  color: const Color(0xff008000), // Green
                  height: 120.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Another example for SingleChildScrollView

```
// Flutter code sample for

// In this example, the column becomes either as big as viewport, or as big as
// the contents, whichever is biggest.

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WidgetsApp(
      title: 'Flutter Code Sample',
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget navigator) {
        return MyStatelessWidget();
      },
      color: const Color(0xffffffff),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
            ),
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    // A fixed-height child.
                    color: const Color(0xff808000), // Yellow
                    height: 120.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    // A flexible child that will grow to fit the viewport but
                    // still be at least as big as necessary to fit its contents.
                    child: Container(
                      color: const Color(0xff800000), // Red
                      height: 120.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Go to your AndroidManifest.xml and remove:
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"  under the application-activity tag.

Basically, just change this:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

to this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        >
```

Worked for one of my apps.

Comment: Thank you for your replay . Actually my problem was it was written "adjustNothing"

Comment: so I change it to "adjustResize" now it works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do this:

```
Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: YOUR_SCROLLING_AREA_HERE,
          ),
          YOUR_PINNED_WIDGET_HERE,
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Title'),
    ),
    body: _buildContent(context),
  );
}
```